# How to set alert view to default

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have an app where I have to use alert view and I know its not possible to set it, so the notification comes in alert view style. How do I set it so that if the user taps that I can they can receive local notifications , it will be automatically set to alert.

Comment: ***I have an app where you have to use alert view and I know its not possible to set it that way***.what do you mean??

Comment: Please be specific, What you want?????

Comment: Sorry, My application requires that a loal notification comes to them in alert view. So how can I set it that way.

Comment: @Jonathan: Will induce more meaning if you specify what you mean by **that** in question. Is it a view? If its a tap action that triggers an alert view, you can rely on UITapGestureRecognizer, and its a good practice to use notification scarcely. Since your question is too vague (I opt not to downvote coz you are new to SOF and since your English seems weak) i suggest you read through [Cocoa Design Patterns Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html) and figure out a proper solution by yourself.

Comment: just edited it for ya'll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply set `UILocalNotification` with my bellow custom method..

```
- (void) scheduleAlarm:(NSString *)PaymentTitle FireDate:(NSDate *)tempFireDate {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];


    NSDate *pickerDate = tempFireDate; //Set yourDate here

    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
  fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
  fromDate:pickerDate];
    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
// Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
//    [dateComps release];//comment it if use ARC

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody =@"Write your Message";
// Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

// Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"iClientManagement" forKey:@"App"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

// Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
//    [localNotif release];//cxomment it if use ARC
}
```

See My this method on [My Blog](http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/10/local-notification.html)

Also see another whole demo from this bellow link for display `UILocalNotifications`

[iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/)

Comment: This is better a comment

Comment: @LithuT.V i know dude that for one line comment is better but i want to post my custom method for `UILocalNotification` so i post the answer.. Thanx :)

Comment: I have three errors 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'
: Use of undeclared identifier 'strProjectName'

Comment: ohh here you use ARC so you get this type of error also in some name like strProjectName is one type of my custom variable so you can write anything on that and comment line where use  `release` and `autorelease`..

Comment: @Jonathan also set date-time which you want instead of **tempFireDate** variable in my above method..

Comment: Should this notification appear as an alert in the simulator?